# QR Code: Is there a way to open an Email app Microsoft Exchange Server Settings by flashing a QR code?

Tags: android

I've read several threads only loosely related to what I'm trying to achieve, so I decided to post anyway. Sorry if this question has already been ***fully** answered, and please point me to the thread where I can find some answers.

Long story short: I'm trying to write a QR code that, when flashed from an Android smartphone, will automatically open the Advanced Settings / Microsoft Exchange Settings in an email application in said smartphone (running Android 7+).

The reason I'm trying to do that is, the company I work for resets email passwords for corporate users all the time, and while we do that on the user's PC via Remote Assistance (users use the same password to access some corporate apps on their PC and receive/send email from the Android phones; that's an unmovable corporate policy), sometimes the email app on the phone will try to sync the Exchange account on the fly, sending connection requests with the old password, thus blocking the account, because as per corporate policy, after five wrong attempts, you're benched, and would you contact your IT support (that's me and my crew).

I'd like to create a QR code from the browser page where the password has been reset, so that the user would only have to flash it using his Android phone camera, resetting his Exchange password on the phone in the process.

Feel free to holler if you need clarification. Any input would be much appreciated...

Comment: going to give you advice here, you're trying to solve one problem and it's several different problems. start by doing QR scanning, there's definitely a way to do that,  then after that focus on opening settings or whatever else you want to do. you are (probably) not going to find an answer to this problem here, because it's not one problem

Comment: Hi, and thanks for taking the time. Actually, I'm trying to input a password or passphrase into an email app on Android phones (mostly Samsung, not all, though) by way of a QR code, so the content of the code is what matters most. Creating a QR code is pretty straightforward, there are lots of ways to do that, even Firefox addons can do it. What I want to do is point the QR code to the right settings in the email app, so that the user's password will automatically be changed.

Comment: In the most sincere way possible, i'm trying to tell you that your question is too broad and not what this site is made for, SO is not for asking general broad advice :) that being said, i am willing to give you my advice :)

Comment: that being said, i have no idea if what you're trying to achieve is possible, no clue if you would be able to automatically launch an email application with a password in it, i also highly doubt you will be able to launch it and change the password immediately

Comment: Hey, I'll take all the advice I can get! How should I phrase it, then? Switch forums? I know you can connect to a WiFi network using a QR code, so I suppose it's possible to enter Settings with a QR code somehow. Thing is, I don't know how... :-/

Comment: well, we both agree that the QR part is entirely possible, so I THINK (my opinion entirely) would be to start off first by finding out what `Microsoft Exchange Server` can do, first google for some documentation for it and check if you can even launch it with passwords pre-populated at all

Comment: That's a good call, I guess. I'm going to check up on that. Right now, the users enter their password manually in the email app, but I'm pretty sure a password manager of some sort could enter it for them too. The key is to get the QR code to open the server settings in the email app, so that the password field can be overwritten.

Comment: so, you'd scan the QR code with some logic (tons of examples for doing that) and then you'd read the content of the QR code and based on what it says, you should be launching `Microsoft Exchange Server`. that part is easy enough, i'm just not sure if you'd be able to populate the password fields.

Comment: When you say it should be easy enough, I'd really like to know what you have in mind! :-) I know my way around Windows, macOS (and OS X before that), some Linux and Unix, but Android is another ball of wax for me. It's probably something about manifest files and the like, but I can't for the life of me figure it out just yet...EDIT: just to clarify things, I'm not trying to launch an Exchange Server, quite the contrary, it's on the client side that I'm hoping to start things a-rolling.

Comment: well https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/read-barcodes has support for barcodes (QR codes too, contrary to the link) maybe you'd be better off trying to find information on an api call you could make for a user to change their password then

Comment: This Firebase thing is most interesting, thank you! I'm gonna try this route, I think, although developping such apps for this client is off-scope. Thanks! In the meantime, if you think of anything else...